# Python-Pandas-Dataframe-datetime conversion excluding null value cells

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, notnull

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I try to convert two date columns in a pandas dataframe using the function below. I use this function, because the "Closed Date" has 4221 lines, so it should not crash on the null cells.

Ultimately, the change results into a dataframe of the original row numbers. So, I don't want to loose the rows that have null values at closed dates.

Dataframe overview:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4272 entries, 0 to 4271
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Created Date    4272 non-null object
Closed Date     4221 non-null object
Agency          4272 non-null object
Borough         4272 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
```

designed function:

```
col='Closed Date'
df[(df[col].notnull())] = df[(df[col].notnull())].apply(lambda    x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

generated error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-155-49014bb3ecb3> in <module>()
      9 
     10 col='Closed Date'
---> 11 df[(df[col].notnull())] = df[(df[col].notnull())].apply(lambda     x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
     12 print(type(df[(df[col].notnull())]))

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in     apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4358                         f, axis,
   4359                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4360                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4361             else:
   4362                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in     _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4454             try:
   4455                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4456                     results[i] = func(v)
   4457                     keys.append(v.name)
   4458             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-155-49014bb3ecb3> in <lambda>(x)
      9 
     10 col='Closed Date'
---> 11 df[(df[col].notnull())] = df[(df[col].notnull())].apply(lambda     x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
     12 print(type(df[(df[col].notnull())]))

TypeError: ('strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series', 'occurred     at index Created Date')
```

Comment: Why don't you use `df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')`? `NaNs` will be stored as `NaTs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need only [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) - it convert `NaN` to `NaT`, so all values are datetimes in column:

```
col='Closed Date'
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Closed Date':['05/01/2016 05:10:10 AM', 
                                  '05/01/2016 05:10:10 AM', 
                                   np.nan]})

col='Closed Date'
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
          Closed Date
0 2016-05-01 05:10:10
1 2016-05-01 05:10:10
2                 NaT

print (df.dtypes)
Closed Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: ah thanks again, second post here so still a bit earning the platform. this reminds me to go to my previous post to accept it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, nice day!